# How can I auto-increment an ID in MySQL with a date of the year in first two digits

Tags: php, mysql

I tried googling for this but haven't found a source or an example. What I want to happen is to have an custom auto-increment with the last two digits of the year in the first two characters of the id, followed by a dash (-) and an 4 or 5 digits with unassigned zero fill that will be unique.

So for example my ID would be like this.

**(17-0001)**

The 17 is the year today and followed by 4 unassigned zero fill digits that will auto generate for the user to be unique. If the year goes by 2018 it will be **18-0002** How can I do this in MySQL using PHP?

Appreciate if someone can help or give some examples on how to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you're looking for is a sequence generator.

Comment: Can you give me some link or example on how to do it?

Comment: There's a lot of ways to do it, but that's the term you're looking for.

Comment: okayokay. Thanks btw! Appreciated it!

Comment: Sequence or Auto-increment feature of respective DB will not help here. you've to develop a custom lookup to achieve this.

Comment: In mysql there is not provision for that, but you can implement it by using server side code like PHP, ASP. Make a table for managing autoincreaments

Comment: Why? Just use an autoincrementing column and a date column, from those you can derive what you asked for.